# Register a Facebook user for an existing web app

Tags: facebook

I have a Flex application that I would like to embed in a Facebook canvas. The app already runs on my website and is accessible there once the user has created an account. I am trying to work out the flow of integrating with Facebook:

1. User accesses my app in Facebook;
2. The app.facebook.com/*myApp* page loads;
3. The Facebook SDk in *myApp* checks if the user is already logged into Facebook, and if not asks them to do so;
4. Once I know the user is logged into Facebook *myApp* will redirect to my server which will check if the Facebook `response.username` already has an account.

   - If the user does not have an account then I create one for them, log them in and redirect them back to the app page with a parameter `hasAccount=true` so that I know they do have an account. I then show them the app;
   - If the user does have an account then I redirect them with `hasAccount=true` and show them the app.

Can anyone comment on that control-flow, is that normal or have I made it overly complicated?

Comment: Just curious, why is creating an account necessary?

Comment: The app needs to store the users data into my database, or when it is reloaded the data will be gone.

Comment: Ok. The steps are normal acc to me then.